# How to fit gridPanels columns?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have application using ExtJs 3.4.
I have this construction:

westPanel-TabPanel:

```
var westPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
            id: "west",
            //xtype: "tabpanel",
            //layout:'fit',
            activeTab: 0,
            region: "west",
            border: false,
            width: 278,
            split: true,
            collapseMode: "mini",
            items: [mapList,structure,cadastr,search]
        });
```

Search - FormPanel:

```
var search = new Ext.FormPanel({
                labelAlign: 'top',
                frame:true,
                title: 'Поиск',
                bodyStyle:'padding:5px 5px 0',
                //width: 600,
                //layout:'fit',
                items: [{
                    xtype:'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Диспечерское наименование',
                    name: 'name_dispather',
                    anchor:'100%',
                    enableKeyEvents: true,
                    listeners: {
                        'keyup': function(e) {
                            if(e.getValue().length==4){
                                searchStore.load({params:{'name':e.getValue()}});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },searchTab]
            });
```

SearchTab - GridPanel:

```
var searchTab = new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.GridPanel({
    store: searchStore,
    region: 'center',
    cm: searchCm, 
    layout: 'fit',
    selModel: new Ext.ux.grid.livegrid.RowSelectionModel(),
    stripeRows : true,
    view: myView,
    height: 390,
    loadMask: true,
    id: 'searchTab',
    title:'Найденные объекты',
    autoScroll: true,
});
```

And i have a problem:

[image]

Have to make last column's width to whole panel's width?

**UPDATE**

I try autoExpandColumn. its works but its not idial:

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with the `flex` config.

You can do it on one column only:

```
columns: [{text: "Column A", dataIndex: "field_A", flex: 1}]
```

Or you can do it as default on all the columns:

```
columns: {
    items: [
        {
            text: "Column A"
            dataIndex: "field_A"
        },{
            text: "Column B",
            dataIndex: "field_B"
        }, 
        ...
    ],
    defaults: {
        flex: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for defaults, only I wouldn't use this since you'll most likely have columns containing a width, and I think flex overrules width.

Comment: flex should only be setted to those columns that are intented to auto-expand. I thinks most times that are never all.

Comment: `@JohanHaest` Flex indeed overwrites any width specified. `@seba` Yes, I thought i'd share it :).

Comment: @A1rPun: defaults not work. Maybe becouse i use ExtJs 3.4?
And i cant find flex property in sencha docs http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column.

Comment: They aren't in the docs because of a [Doc Bug]. And for defaults to work, you must add items by their xtype (I can't find defaults too in 3.4 docs).

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

`autoExpandColumn :` String

The id of a column in this grid that should expand to fill unused space.

This config option you have to provide for your searchTab (I mean the grid panel).

EDITED:

```
  viewConfig:{
      scrollOffset: 0,
  forceFit: true
  },
```

This will remove that gap left for scrollbar. This you need to mention for your searchTab (I mean the grid panel).

Comment: according to sencha this is obsolete and should not be used

Comment: @vajrakumar: I try autoExpandColumn. Its works but with one problem like om screen in question update.

Comment: That space is for scroll bar , if record comes more then scroll bar will come at that place.

Any how we can make this space go.
Give some time will post it.

Comment: @Kliver Max : I think the above edit solved your problem.
If not come up with the further doubts, but don't forget to accept the answer after you find solution. It will help others while searching to refer only accepted answer.